# sending data parameters to rest api using python-requests

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I am trying to call `rest api` by sending `json` data. The curl command is pretty straight forward but only problem that I am facing is with "--data" parameter.

For curl, the data is sent as follows:

```
curl -X POST -H <headers> --data 'params={...}' <url>
```

I am not able to figure out how to send the --data parameter with the name `'params='`attached to it using python-requests.

Also while making GET requests, there are a lot of options which I have to send along with the `curl requests(-O ,-J, -v, -G,-L)`.

I wanted to know how to supply these additional parameters using python-requests.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you interested in sending request parameters in the URL? I am referring to the bold bit of the following URL: something.com/get?  **key2=value2&key1=value1**

Answer (score 0):

`curl` is a very rich library that has gone far way after a lot of developments in last decades. Compare to the `curl`, python's `requests` library is still a baby. So you can not expect all the functionalities of `curl` in `requests`. You'll only get the major functionalities of `curl` in your `requests`.

Now come to your question. If you want to send the json data through a variable, then the basic POST operation(`content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) will do.

```
payload = {'params': json_string}
r = requests.post("http://url/post", data=payload)
```

But if you want to POST the data as json object with header content-type as json, then you have to use this

```
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post(url, data=json_string, headers=headers)
```

In Curl the param -L means for following the redirection. You can achieve it with `allow_redirects=True` parameter:

```
r = requests.post(url, data=json_string, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True)
```

Help yourself to find your needs from the requests [document](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/).

Comment: Hi Sabuj, Thanks for your comments. Although that did not help me much. But I finally executed the curl commands from within the os.system() function. Using it I was also able to view the response from the curl commands. There is subprocess library in python which is recommended instead of os.system(). But I am yet to figure how to access the response headers using subprocess library(python-requests has the response object's headers attribute which can be used for the same). Anyways thanks for your reply. It was informative. Cheers !!!

Comment: small edit there. I did not view the response headers from curl command using os.system(). I only got the response. I slightly got confused since I was working on multiple projects. One using python-requests, other using os.system(). Thanks.